# Develop attractive gui in linux

Tags: java, linux, user-interface

I'm a newbie in the world of linux development.
I have used linux os in the past (ubuntu, sabayon and gentoo for a little time).
Actually I'm mainly a .net c# developer and I have done some Android app.

My company, for a new project, ask me to develop a Linux application in java with a attractive gui.
I' ve searched around on the net and I have found only old topics about this.
I have read about swing but.. swing has born in 1996 and probably is a little old tecnology.

I have read about vaadin but is for web app and it cannot permit to use SO utility, read folders ecc.

Someone can suggest me what can I use? 
And what editor I use for the design of a good gui?
Thank you all for any answers and excuse me for my bad english.

Comment: Yes, Swing is outdated. You should look at JavaFX for a desktop application.

Comment: "E quale editor posso utilizzare per la progettazione di un buon gui" = "Which editor can I use to design a button" ?

Comment: If Java was just a suggestion, rather than a requirement, I'd suggest [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org).

Comment: I strongly advise you to look at javafx, I have used it a for a couple of my own projects and it is basically awesome. The JavaFX Scene Builder tool is also really nice to use. IDE wise I use eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want content rich (UI wise) applications, you should take a look at [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784) since it should offer better functionality than the older Swing counter part.

As far as IDE's, I have used [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) on all the Linux distributions I have owned (including Sabayon) and it should provide you with a GUI interface builder (much like the designer in Visual Studio). You can take a look at [this](https://netbeans.org/features/java-on-client/javafx.html) Netbeans page for more directions on how to use Netbeans to build a UI application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QT Jambi if you find it appropriate 
[https://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Jambi](https://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt%5fJambi)
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077750/core-java/java-desktop-development-with-qt-jambi.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for great performance with a Java GUI you can try jmonkeyengine http://jmonkeyengine.org/ (play store on android is made with this engine) or libgdx (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

They are mainly used for games, but GUI with many animations and interactions should look pretty fine with them. Also, they can be used for desktop AND android.